# HTML <video> tag - key events not received without controls attribute | Event#preventDefault not cancelling controls

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have attempted to display a video with custom controls. It seems to be working fine, but I have one problem. The `controls` attribute seem to be causing problems when I try to listen for key events.

I currently have this piece of code for testing:

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video");

video.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    console.log("keypress");
    console.log(`  Key: ${event.which}`);
    
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I have done the same for `keydown` as well, but it has the same problem. The problem being one of two things:

- If the `<video>` tag does **not** have the `controls` attribute: The event is never received, so the messages never get printed to the console.
- If the `<video>` tag has the `controls` attribute: The event is received and the messages are printed to the console, but the `event.preventDefault()` call does not stop the behaviour caused by having the `controls` attribute, so I can still play/pause the video using space (it does stop me from using enter, for some reason), seek using the left/right arrow keys, and adjust the volume using the up/down arrow keys.

Q&A:

- Q: Have you tried reacting to the event(s) not on the video element
  itself, but something like a wrapper div? Not sure if that makes a
  difference, but I’d figure it might be worth a try.
- A: Yes. I did try that, but unfortunately, it only received the key events when the focus was on my custom control buttons.

I have attempted to find a solution for the past day, but to no avail. If you have any suggestions, please do let me know.

Comment: Have you tried reacting to the event(s) not on the video element itself, but something like a wrapper div? Not sure if that makes a difference, but I’d figure it might be worth a try.

Comment: Yes. I did try that, but unfortunately, it only received the key events when the focus was on my custom control buttons.

Comment: By [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#htmlvideoelement), `<video>` element should not take JS commands when `control` attribute is present.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it has some great information. Unfortunately, I thought that might be the case, so how would you suggest I go about this?

Comment: You've either to implement all your own controls, or use the native controls, these can't be mixed.

Comment: I did make custom controls in the form of buttons on the page, but I wanted to remove or edit some of the keyboard shortcuts, however, I am not sure how to go about this if I can neither listen to the event nor cancel it.

Comment: Actually, I can't [reproduce your issue](https://jsfiddle.net/tr4mpj1L/), at least hitting space on the play/pause button is prevented ..? If you want to prevent keyboard shortcuts, you could try to listen to `keydown` event (it's the only not-deprecated cancelable keyboard event) on `document` in capture phase instead of listening it on the element.

Comment: I had the same problem when using the code in the fiddle (I only added a source for the video to test it, otherwise, there was no difference), but I just tested capture mode on the document, and it was exactly what I was looking for! It allowed me to cancel the presses, so I can finally make them do what I want. I just made sure to check the event's target before cancelling.

Comment: Maybe it's browser-dependent, I tested with Firefox only, and in FF `keydown` on `video` event is fired and the default action is prevented when running the linked example.

Comment: It might be browser-dependent (I do not have Firefox installed, so I cannot check with that), but the event does fire with my chromium browser, however, despite the fact that `event.preventDefault()` does get called, the video controls' keyboard shortcuts still worked. Thankfully, the document listener in capture phase did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working, after typing back and forth through the comments.

Listening for the `keydown` event on the document in capture phase allows me to use `event.preventDefault()`. I just have to add some conditions so it does not cancel all key presses in the document.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video");

document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.target !== video) return;
    
    // Space has keyCode 32
    if (event.which === 32) event.preventDefault();
}, true);
```